# push error: master: master [rejected non-fast-forward]

Tags: android, eclipse, git

Consider, I am new in GitHub..I am starting to push an Android project to my git repository from eclipse. But after a long trying i can't reached success. I don't use terminal or can't use it.  I use EGit plug-in for eclipse. I followed a video tutorial on YouTube.

After completing the steps for push to remote branch from pushing my local Android project to I remote branch got this error.

[image]

How I solve this in GUI mode or How to use terminal for pushing local to remote? 
Any link or tutorial should be appreciated.

Comment: From terminal it is easy enough: git push origin <branchname>, so likely in this case it would be "git push origin master".

Comment: @aet: how to use terminal? explain a bit

Comment: What OS are you on? Windows? Linux? Mac? Each a little different. I often find it easier when dealing with bitbucket or github to create the repo via github website, then clone it via eclipse/egit, then add code to it.

Comment: @aet: windows. ya I open repository in Git website. then push project file into that repository from Eclipse/Egit.

Comment: On windows, you would need to open a command prompt and change directories to your workspace. From there you should be able to run "git status", it will be helpful in troubleshooting. I suspect you are out of sync with origin, probably need to run "git pull" before pushing.

Comment: @aet thanks. working hope, keep in touch in this qs.

Answer (score 3):

The "**[Push Confirmation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Push_Confirmation)**" step isn't an error:

> This will open the Push Confirmation dialog showing a preview which changes will be pushed to the destination repository.
>   If this does not match your expectation click Back and correct your push specs accordingly.

That message means the only way to complete the push is to **force** it (you would erase the remote history, replacing it with the one your are pushing).

The prudent course of action is first to make a `git pull`: see "[Pulling New Changes from Upstream Branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Pulling_New_Changes_from_Upstream_Branch)" for the EGit version.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I solved this as follows for an existing git repository:

In Eclipse's project browser, right click on the project and select "Import..." then choose Git > Projects from Git. Click next, choose URI, click next, then enter the info. Store your user/pass in secure store if you don't want to enter it every time you push. Choose your branch, then click next. Hopefully this takes you far enough to where you can figure it out.

To Commit and Push, right click on the project, go to Team > Commit, and choose Commit and Push after entering your commit message and selecting the files to commit. You should then be able to select the existing repository from the dropdown, which makes pushing much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to `push ref specifications` and check `force update` next to your previously added `spec` and then click `finish` again.

[image]